# RequestFactory with ValueType for interfaces / abstract classes

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Following are my domain classes

```
class Person { 
     String getName(); 
     Vehicle getVehicle(); 
} 

interface Vehicle { 
   String getCompanyName(); 
   String getRegNo(); 
   Point getParkingSpaceRequired(); 
} 

abstract class AbstractVehicle { 
} 

class Motorcycle extends AbstractVehicle { 
} 

class Car extends AbstractVehicle { 
}
```

Creating PersonProxy as EntityProxy was straight forward, and working fine for person.getName()

I have created VehicleProxy as ValueProxy and called fire() with .with('vehicle') 
But I am getting error:

*The domain type com....AbstractVehicle$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e86549b9 cannot be sent to the client.*

On PersonProxy 
I got @ProxyFor(value=Person.class,locator=PersonLocator.class)
On VehicleProxy I got @ProxyFor(value=Vehicle.class)

so, How to handle such inheritance in RequestFactory?
Should I change Vehicle to EntityProxy from ValueProxy?
Then How to implement methods of VehicleLocator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write proxy interfaces for `Motorocycle` and `Car` instead of proxy interface for interface `Vehicle`. I've never used requestfactory proxy interfaces for interfaces (not classes), and in my opinion that's the reason you are getting this exception.

[EDIT]
In such case as above, you will have to move `Vehicle` interface to the `shared` package so that both server and client site would see it. That's very common solution in case of enums - domain classes has some enum property and proxy interface must also contains accessors for this property.

Other solution (which I think may not work) is to write proxy interface for `Vehicle` interface and your proxy interfaces for `Motorocycle` and `Car` should extend it.

Comment: So what should be returned from getVehicle() of PersonProxy? Vehicle? 
and MotorcycleProxy should extend Vehicle interface? or I should have VehicleProxy?

Comment: Right, I missed this part - sorry. Please take a look at my edits.